# How can I solve it (modification of famous robot travelling problem)?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

Imagine you have to solve this [question](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-possible-paths-top-left-bottom-right-nxm-matrix/) (+ you have obstacles, i.e. walls), but you're allowed to move in any of 4 directions (not just 2: down and right). How can you solve it? I'm struggling to apply the same dynamic programming principle.

EDIT: [one more similar question](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/What-is-the-total-number-of-distinct-paths-in-a-nxm-grid-starting-from-top-left-corner-to-bottom-right-corner-if-movement-in-all-the-directions-are-allowed).

Comment: Can you include the relevant parts of the other questions in your post?

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.  I'd suggest studying [our resources on dynamic programming](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info), try applying them on your own, and then edit your question to show your progress so far and what subproblem decompositions you've tried.